# Is this set open in the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and if so, how can it be represented as a union of open balls?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am working on an exercise in a real analysis book and have come to a point where I'm not sure what to do. In my proof, I have defined sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (where $n\in\mathbb{N}$) that have the following form:
\begin{equation}
E(x,\hat{r}) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} \hat{B}(x_{i},\hat{r}_{i}) 
\end{equation}
Here $\hat{B}(x_{i},\hat{r}_{i})$ is an open ball (i.e. open interval)
in $\mathbb{R}$ with center $x_{i}$ and radius $\hat{r}_{i}$. Here
$\hat{r}_{i}$ can equal $\infty$ so that $\hat{B}(x_{i},\hat{r}_{i})$
can be equal to $\mathbb{R}$.

Is it true that every such $E(x,\hat{r})$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ ?
If so, how do you write a given $E(x,\hat{r})$ as the union of a set of
open balls in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ ? Since the set of open balls in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is
a basis for the Eucldean topology, if $E(x,\hat{r})$ is open shouldn't there be a way to do it ?

Comment: If an open interval has infinite length, it does not mean that it is the whole of $\mathbb{R}$ e.g. $(0,\infty)$. The notion of open/closed balls arises from a *metric*, not a topology. Do you mean to use the Euclidean metric? (this corresponds to the Euclidean topology, and gives the 'spherical' open balls that one would expect)

Comment: This may or may not be new info to you, but if the $\hat{r}_{i}$'s are all finite, then $E$ can be visualized as a rectangular block (without boundaries). To get a clearer conceptual view of this, ask yourself: how is a filled rectangle (without boundaries) in $n=2$ a union of open balls?

Comment: Oliver, the question asked "Prove that the product topology on $R^{n}$ agrees with the Euclidean topology on $R^{n}$." This is in section 2 of a chapter on topology. Metric spaces seem to be introduced in the next section (section 3).

Comment: @scipio Your question title asks if $E(x,\hat{r})$ can be expressed as a union of open balls. This doesn't make much sense without reference to metric spaces, or indeed without stating which metric you are using (which is why I cite the three most common choices in my answer). The Euclidean topology is usually defined to be the topology induced by the Euclidean metric, which again refers to metric spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Open intervals are open in $\mathbb{R}$ (bounded or otherwise) w.r.t. the metric $d(x,y):=|x-y|$. Your set $E(x,\hat{r})$ is a product of open sets in $\mathbb{R}$, so must be open in the the [product topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology) on $\mathbb{R}^n$, which happens to coincide with the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

The open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ w.r.t. the Euclidean metric $$d_2(x,y):=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i-y_i|\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$ coincide with the open sets in the Euclidean topology (we say that the Euclidean metric *induces* the Euclidean topology).

In a metric space, every open set can be expressed as a union of open balls, and $E(x,\hat{r})$ is open in the Euclidean metric. It follows that it can be expressed as a union of open balls. When all of your open intervals are bounded, this amounts geometrically to saying that a 'cube' in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be expressed as a union of 'spheres' in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

However, there are other well-known metrics on $\mathbb{R}^n$ that induce the Euclidean topology e.g. $$d_1(x,y):=\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i-y_i|$$ and $$d_\infty(x,y):=\max_{1\leq i\leq n}|x_i-y_i|.$$ $E(x,\hat{r})$ can be expressed as a union of open balls in *any* metric that has the same open sets as for the Euclidean metric, such as $d_1$ and $d_\infty$ above.

On your final question: Every open set in the Euclidean topology can be expressed as a union of open balls in any metric that induces the Euclidean topology. Therefore, the open balls in each of these metrics form a basis for the Euclidean topology. But note that each metric gives different open balls.

Answer (score 1):

An equivalent way of stating that $E(x, r)$ is a union of open balls is saying that for every $y \in E(x, r)$, there is an open ball $B$ containing $y$ such that $B \subseteq E(x, r)$. For your set, it is easy to show that it is open using this method. More generally, the same proof shows that if $X_1, \dots, X_n$ are metric spaces, and $U_i \subseteq X_i$ are open, then $U_1 \times \dots \times U_n$ is open in $X_1 \times \dots \times X_n$ equipped with any one of the equivalent product metrics.